# overflow-y not working with ng-if in Internet Explorer with Angular

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, overflow, angular-ng-if

I am using Angular 1.2.16 and testing with IE 11.

In my app, in settings.html, I have the following section:

```
<section class='scrollable'> 
 <section class='hbox stretch'>
  <aside class="aside-md bg-white b-r" data-ng-controller='RecipientsCtrl'> 
   <div data-ng-if='inputMode'  data-ng-include="'partials/recipient-form.html'"/>
 </section>
</section>
```

where 'scrollable' class is defined as:

```
.scrollable {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

and recipient.form:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <form name='rform' ng-submit='addRecipient(rform)' novalidate='novalidate' role="form">
    <label>Recipient's Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model='recipient.name' name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required='', data-mongoose-error=''/>
    ....
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Add</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

A button click puts the controller in 'inputMode'. This works fine with Chrome, Safari and Firefox. In IE, when you click the button to get into the 'inputMode' it seems like nothing happens, but when you resize the window a bit you see the form.

The following makes it work in IE:

- Remove the 'scrollable' class from the section (not an option as I need that)
- Display the form directly without the 'inputMode' condition (not an option)

I tried ng-show as well at no avail.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the css seems to have fixed it:

```
.scrollable {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```